# Solving a system with a nonlinear polynomial inequality

Tags: inequality, nonlinear-system

This is a very (very) basic problem, but I do not know how to proceed. In general, how to proceed when facing a system of nonlinear polynomial inequalities like this one?

\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
\alpha x + \beta xy + \gamma y \leq \delta,\\
x \geq 0 ,\\
x \leq 1,\\
y \geq 0 ,\\
y \leq 1,\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Thanks a lot in advance for any feedback.

Comment: You can write it as $\,\beta\left(x+ \gamma/\beta\right)\left(y+\alpha/\beta\right)-\alpha\gamma/\beta-\delta \le 0\,$. When $\,= 0\,$ equality holds, that's the equation of a hyperbola, so you need to find the region(s) where the LHS is negative within the square $\,[0,1]\times[0,1]\,$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually, playing around I found that path. More in general, beyond this particular example, how should we proceed when trying to solve a system of polynomial inequalities with one 'objective' function in $k$ variables $x_k$ and $k$ constraints $x_k \in [0,1]$?

Comment: The way in which I was writing above sounds to me very close to optimization, but there is no actual optimization involved